# Flash detect array index of clicked movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an array of movieclip class and give it clickHandler to detect mouse click on my movieclip.

```
var _drone:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 0;i<25;i++)
{
    _drone[i] = new drone();
    _drone[i].y = (Math.random()*-1000)+35;
    _drone[i].x = (Math.random()*400)+35;   
    _drone[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
    _drone[i].stop();       
    addChild(_drone[i]);
}

function clickHandler (event:MouseEvent):void {
    //start animation
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to detect which drone I'm clicking to start the animation. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function clickHandler (event:MouseEvent):void {
    //start animation
    event.currentTarget.play();
}
```

See [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget).